# Slow Lubuntu (memory leaks?) : what can/should I do?

Tags: performance

So I have a pretty modern utrabook (1.7GHz Core i5-2557M processor, 4GB of RAM) with Lubuntu on it.

It is pretty fast, but sometimes, after quite some while (and many browser tabs open + a rails server running for quite a while), it can get slow ... really slow ...

I'm trying to figure out where the memory leak is. Thing is, I have no clue how to analyse the task monitor, and to possibly close the leaking program, instead of having to reboot.

[image: Take memory]

Questions:

- What is the best resources indicator? CPU ? RSS ? Memory ? State ?
- Is there anywhere else I could look around to analyse memory leaks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Monitor program you are using is more than enough for the Job.

It seems that Chrome is memory hungry. Try using firefox.

By the way there is no problem if your RAM is full. Because the kernel take care of unused apps and put them in swap.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can you tell Chrome is memory hungry on the table? By reading 180.5Mb RSS or 948.1Mb Memory? Is sublime text also very hungry with 94Mb RSS and 1.1Gb Memory? I extensively use chrome (40 tabs open, several developper tools open etc.) so I don't criticize the memory usage but I just wanted to know what I should do when my computer gets really slow, better than restart the system!

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Generally in Linux. There is no need to restart. Just close unwanted apps. Yes Chrome is shown 180.5 and 948.1 respectively in Memory and RSS => implies memory hungry

Comment: Does sublime 94Mb RSS and 1.1Gb Memory => memory hungry too?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Yes. But almost all IDEs like netbeans,sublime,... need memory. try disabling plugins or install  minimal version